# Pushing back an object to a list in c++

Tags: c++, list, oop, object, operator-overloading

I have an issue with pushing back object to a list of objects.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Class1& sk) {
    os << sk.X << 'x' << sk.Y << 'x' << sk.H << ';' << sk.a << ';' << sk.b << '\n';
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Class1& sk) {
    char ch;
    is >> sk.X >> ch >> sk.Y >> ch >> sk.H >> ch >> sk.a >> ch >> sk.b >> ch;
    return is;
}

void Class1::GetSK_list(std::list<Class1>& SK_list) {
    std::ifstream file("file.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::list<Class1>::iterator iter = SK_list.begin();
    while(file >> *iter) {
        "std::cout << *iter"; // checking
        SK_list.push_back(*iter);
        iter++;
    }
    file.close();
}

void Class1::SaveSK_list(std::list<Class1>& SK_list) {
    std::ofstream file("file.txt", std::ios::out);
    for(std::list<Class1>::iterator iter = SK_list.begin(); iter != SK_list.end(); iter++)
        file << *iter;
    file.close();
}
```

When I'm using SaveSK_list function, it works correctly.

The problem is with GetSK_list function. If there's one line in file (e.g. 1x2x3;4;5) file >> *iter doesn't work. There's nothing printed (I believe std::cout << *iter is never reached).

If there's more than one line in file, only the very first one is being printed. [After that std::bad_alloc error appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgyu0.png)

Btw. these functions are in Class1 in order to use operators overloading.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If `SK_list` is empty when you call `GetSK_list`, then `file >> *iter` will be undefined behavior.  Even if it is not empty your loop doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `"std::cout << *iter"`.... try without the `"`. If that is the code you will not see output from `std::cout`

Comment: Instead of `while(file >> *iter)` (which is the issue), read into an instance of `Class1` (e.g. `Class1 temp;`) and `file >> temp` and then call `.push_back(temp);`

Comment: _"(I believe std::cout << *iter is never reached)."_ Using your debugger, find out for sure.

Comment: I've changed while loop to `while(file >> tmp) SK_list.push_back(tmp)` where tmp is an instance of Class1 like @DavidC.Rankin suggested. Also, operator >> overloading needed update: `is >> sk.X >> ch >> sk.Y >> ch >> sk.H >> ch >> sk.a >> ch >> sk.b;`. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [an insert iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), which will automatically call `push_back()` on the list:

```
void GetSK_list(std::list<Class1>& SK_list) {
    auto iter = std::back_inserter(SK_list);

    std::ifstream file("file.txt", std::ios::in);
    Class1 tmp;
    while(file >> tmp) {
        *iter++ = tmp;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

You can do even better by combining with an `istream_iterator` and the `copy` algorithm:

```
void GetSK_list(std::list<Class1>& SK_list) {
    std::ifstream file("file.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Class1>(file),
              std::istream_iterator<Class1>(),
              std::back_inserter(SK_list));
}
```

There's also no need to call `file.close()`; the file is closed in the `ifstream` destructor.

Comment: `.push_back()` is a valid way to insert in [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)